# Github Workflow can't find docker compose file

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, github-actions

```yaml
name: Integration Test

on:
    push:
        branches: [main]

jobs:
    test:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - name: Start Services
              run: |
                  docker-compose up -d
                  sleep 20

            - name: Run Integration Tests
              run: python tests/integration.py

            - name: Stop Services
              run: docker-compose down
```

It's a very simple github action script.
It doesn't find the docker-compose.yaml file.

The error is:

```
Run docker-compose up -d

        Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml, compose.yml, compose.yaml
        
Error: Process completed with exit code 1
```

The file structure is:

[image: 1]

Why does this happen?

Comment: You need to use the [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) as your job first step to be able to access the repository files: `- uses: actions/checkout@v3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GuiFalourd answered my question.

I had to create a step to checkout the code:

```
        steps:
            - name: Checkout Code
              uses: actions/checkout@v2
```